# Retrieve word document from SQL Database

Tags: vb.net

I need to retrieve word document attached in sql database (saved as varbinary(MAX) )  .. i got string like '??????'  in richtextBox..any help how to retrieve it in richbox or word document in vb.net ..many thanks

```
        Dim docID As Integer = patDocGridView.SelectedRows(0).Cells("ID").Value.ToString()
        Dim doc_File As PatientDocument = _context.PatientDocument.Where(Function(a As PatientDocument) a.ID = docID).FirstOrDefault

        If Not (IsDBNull(doc_File)) Then
            Dim buffer() As Byte = CType(doc_File.Doc_File, Byte())

            Dim myString As String = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer)
            rtbPatDocFile.Text = myString
        Else
            rtbPatDocFile.Clear()
        End If
```

Comment: What is `PatientDocument` where is this defined

Comment: What do you get in `myString` ? and how do you save document in database ?

Answer (score 0):

```
            Dim ms As New MemoryStream()
            ms.Write(row.Field(Of Byte())("info"), 0, row.Field(Of Byte())("info").Length)
            ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin)
            LoginInfoBox.LoadFile(ms, RichTextBoxStreamType.RichText)
```

Where LoginInfoBox is a RichTextBox.

This loads a record from a datatable from a MySQL database, and displays it in the richtextbox.  In my case the file in the database is an rtf.

I don't think you can use encoding ascii as the word file wont be ascii. you could try encoding.utf8, and you can't use a string to the best of my knowledge, to store the word file in.

row is a datarow containing the row from the database  (info is the field containing the rtf)

Comment: Part of your problem is the ascii encoding, word files will have control characters which are not ascii.  Try encoding.utf8